Googleの管理コンソールで設定する組織部門に特定の役割を設定する事は可能でしょうか？
APIでの組織取得について質問をさせてください。
Googleが提供するAPIを用い、組織情報の取得を行っております。
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest?hl=ja
現在、純粋に管理コンソールにて設定を行ったツリー情報を取得する事は出来ているのですが、
ツリー階層に特定の属性を持たせ、その属性に該当する組織だけを取得出来ないか？と考えております。
株式会社
┣開発部
┃┣チームＡ
┃┗チームＢ
┣法務部
┗総務部
具体的には、上記のようなツリー階層になっていた際に、部署（開発部、法務部、総務部）のみを取得できないか？といった内容となります。
管理コンソール上から組織部門を設定する際は、『名前』と『説明』の2項目を文字列で入力しかできません。
その為、どの組織がどういった用途で…といった設定が出来ないのですが、ライセンス等で追加要素の設定が可能だったりしますでしょうか？
少し用途は違いますが、MicrosoftのTeamsですと作成時に部門やクラス等の用途が設定できる為、同様の事が出来ないか？との想いでした。
Googleとしてはそういった役割を持たせる機能は持たせておらず、
・末尾が『部』の組織を部署として取り扱う
・特定の組織の直下の組織を部署として取り扱う
といった名前、説明からフィルタリングをかける方法しかないのでしょうか？
もし、本件につきまして何かご存じな方がおられましたらご回答いただけますと幸いです。
